# Send Email with PDF Attachment Using PHP - File Delivered Corrupt

Tags: php, email, pdf, attachment

I'm brand new to php and am using the following code to send an email with a PDF attachment.
The Code seems to almost be working. The Email is sent and the file is attached.

However when attempting to open the file it is saying that the file is corrupt.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $filename = 'My File.pdf';
    $path = '/public_html';
    $file = $path . "/" . $filename;

    $mailto = 'themark@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $message = 'My message';

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: Jennifer <jenniferk@gmail.co.uk>" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: Jennifer <jenniferk@gmail.co.uk>" .$eol;
    $headers .= "Return-Path: Jennifer <jenniferk@gmail.co.uk>" .$eol;     // these two to set reply address
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    //SEND Mail
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You’re going wrong in trying to assemble a proper multipart mail manually … use a mailer library such as PHPMailer or Swift Mailer.

Comment: @CBroe i'm sorry but I'm completely new to PHP and don't understand what that means.

Comment: The syntax to properly assemble a multipart mail is complex, and it is more than easy to make mistakes with that. Therefor, instead of doing this manually, you should rather use an already existing library written specifically for such purposes, where you won’t have to do all this yourself, but would just call a method it provides, to add an attachment to your mail.